# Is it safe to access a member via child class, if you use templates in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, intellisense

It sounds like a strange question, but when I use the following example code in Visual Studio 2022, IntelliSense is warning me that the member `iMember` in the parent class is inaccessible, even though the code itself seems ok to me and is running without any problems.

**Example Code:**

```
template<class S, class T> class Child;

template<class S, class T>
class Base {
    int iMember = 0;
public:
    Base(const Child<S, T>& child);
    Base(int iMember) : iMember(iMember) {}
    void Print() { std::cout << iMember << std::endl; }
};

template<class S, class T>
class Child : public Base<S, T>{
public:
    Child(int i) : Base<S,T>(i) {}
};

//the following constructor causes the IntelliSense warning that Base<S,T>::iMember is inaccessible 
template<class S, class T>
Base<S, T>::Base(const Child<S, T>& child) : iMember(child.iMember) {}

int main() {
    Child<int, int> cc(234);
    Base<int, int> bb(cc);
    cc.Print(); //prints 234
}
```

I have no idea why IntelliSense is making this warning, but maybe my code has an undefined behavior.

Comment: Don't rely on intellisense too much. It has no "sense". I would suggest to just turn of intellisense altogether.

Comment: Accessing rules are not dependent on templates. Your baseclass has a private member so it is not accessible in the derived class. You will need to make it protected.

Comment: *"but maybe my code has an undefined behavior...."* No there is no UB in the above program. It is well-defined. Intellisense is known to have these kind of bugs.

Comment: Intellisense can be dumb. Clangd is better (especially if you use Clang as the compiler, then they never disagree), but I'm not sure if VS can use it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Note that in the member initializer list of the base class writing `child.iMember` is perfectly fine as we're in the scope of the base class. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GfMeqWf43). That is, there is no need to make the member `protected` here.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer: In addition to what user12002570 just wrote, I would like to add that making the member protected will not remove the IntelliSense warning. The only way to remove the warning is to make the parent class a friend of the child class AND vice versa. Since IntelliSense is bugged anyway, there is probably no point going further into details here.

Comment: Trust your compiler error and warning over intellisense. Intellisense might not be always right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"but maybe my code has an undefined behavior...."*

The program is well-defined i.e there is no UB in the given code.

---

> the following constructor causes the IntelliSense warning that `Base<S,T>::iMember` is inaccessible

This is a **false positive**. In the constructor initializer list of the base class, we can safely/correctly write `child.iMember` because we're in the scope of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that the IntelliSense warning you are encountering appears to be a false positive rather than an actual issue with your code. The code you provided correctly initializes the `Base<S, T>::iMember` in the constructor `Base<S, T>::Base(const Child<S, T>& child)` through the member initializer list, which is a valid and appropriate practice.

It's not uncommon for static analysis tools like IntelliSense to occasionally generate false positives or negatives. In this case, since your code compiles and runs without any problems and there are no runtime issues, it is reasonable to dismiss the IntelliSense warning as a tooling quirk.